# Preventing two markers in the same place Google Maps SDK iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, dictionary

How can I prevent two markers from being placed at the same location on the map?

I'm setting an array of `var markerLocations = [CLLocation2D]()` and while I'm making my new marker to be placed, I want to check against that array and make sure there's not a location that is in the same spot as mine before I place it.

When using `.contains` it appears that you can only check a single value? Is there a way to check if both the lat and the long are equal to the location I'm trying to check against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting the lat long to a consistent string representation, and caching those representations in a dictionary.

First, truncate the lat long to a suitable number of decimal places, and then convert it to a string of the form `"lat0.12345long-1.23456"`. Then, for each item store `true` in a `[String:Bool]` dictionary. Then, each time you want to insert a new location, generate the appropriate key string from the new location, and check whether it exists in the dictionary, and then insert it only if it isn't already there. This should work well even with large number of locations since looking up keys in dictionaries is much faster than checking whether an array contains an item.